# Codahale meter simple moving average

Tags: java, codahale-metrics

I am using java codahale metrics library. I am using a meter. The meter automatically produces m1_rate, m5_rate and m15_rate but these rates are exponentially weighted.

Is there a way to generate simple moving averages (without exponential weighting) ?